Unable to install anything with CLI sdkmanager on WSL: failed to find package
Unable to install anything with sdkmanager CLI. The warnings should be a clue; searched the web and the official documentation but didn't find anything helpful.
See outputs below:
$ sdkmanager --version
12.0

$ sdkmanager --licenses

All SDK package licenses accepted.

$ sdkmanager update
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
Warning: Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Warning: Failed to find package 'update'


$ sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33"
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
Warning: Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
Warning: Failed to find package 'platform-tools'

Extracts from --verbose:
Info: Parsing legacy package: /opt/android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest
Info: IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml
Info: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_d2b9d222-addons_list-5_xml
...
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/user/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_b7518f9e-repository2-3_xml
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
...

Environment: Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Using sdkmanager from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip.
Tried both with:
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_422"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_422-8u422-b05-1~24.04-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.422-b05, mixed mode)

And
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-9889599 (build 17.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-9889599 (build 17.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Is there something missing in my setup? I do have a working development environment on Windows with the GUI SDK manager from Android Studio, but this is a command-line only setup on WSL, so only command-line solutions please. Thank you!
